# how to display default(static) text to jquery autocomplete dropdown

Tags: jquery-autocomplete

I have a jquery autocomplete and it works just fine. Now i want to add a default text in the dropdown like

Input box if the user types.. ja

It should display below

Select below category [should be there all the time]

java

javascript

Any suggestion on how to do it..

```
  // Ajax Auto suggestion box

    var options, a;
    jQuery(function()
    {

    a = $('#txtOccupation').autocomplete({
      serviceUrl: '/App_Handlers/GetAjaxSuggestions.ashx?datasets=occ',
      minChars: 1,
      delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/,
      deferRequestBy: 0, //miliseconds
      noCache: false,
      width: 420,
      onSelect: function(value, data){ alert('You selected: ' + value + ', ' + data);             },
     });



    browser = jQuery.browser;
    $('.autocomplete').css('padding-left','10px');
    });
```

HTML

```
**  <input type="text" class="placeholder-text" maxlength="100" value="Job title, Keyword or O*NET code" onfocus="if(this.value=='Job title, Keyword or O*NET code')this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Job title, Keyword or O*NET code'" id="txtOccupation" name="txtOccupations" autocomplete="off"></input>**
```

Comment: Based on the below fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/J5rVP/158/ ,the below code is adding the text  response: function (e, ui) {
                    ui.content.push(
                      { label: "Other", value: "Other" }
                    );
                }  But its adding at the end, i want it to be on top.

Comment: Added answer for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am providing answer to:

`But its adding at the end, i want it to be on top.` in your comment.

Based on the below your fiddle [jsfiddle.net/J5rVP/158](http://jsfiddle.net/J5rVP/158), I forked new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/a3Tun/ to add element at top.

I have changed `ui.content.push` to `ui.content.unshift`.

`unshift` is like `push`, but it insert value at top of array. For more info, refer http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unshift.asp