# JQuery Ajax Autocomplete - Response event is not firing

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Below is my code ,the autocomplete works fine but i want to add default text in the autocomplete dropdown ,which i did as per below thread 
[how to display default(static) text to jquery autocomplete dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23522253/how-to-display-defaultstatic-text-to-jquery-autocomplete-dropdown#comment36088191_23522253)

The actual implementation is little different and i am not able to get the response to work

```
var options, a;
jQuery(function() {
    var __response = $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._response;
    $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._response = function(content) {
        __response.apply(this, [content]);
        this.element.trigger("autocompletesearchcomplete", [content]);
    };

    a = $('#txtOccupation').autocomplete({
        serviceUrl: '/App_Handlers/GetAjaxSuggestions.ashx?datasets=occ',
        minChars: 1,
        delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/,
        deferRequestBy: 0, //miliseconds
        noCache: false,
        width: 420,
        onSelect: function(value, data) {
            alert('You selected: ' + value + ', ' + data);
        },
        response: function(e, ui) {
            ui.content.unshift({label: "OR select an occupation:", value: "OR select an occupation:"});
        }
    }).bind("autocompletesearchcomplete", function(event, contents) {
        alert(contents.length);
    });
    browser = jQuery.browser;
    $('.autocomplete').css('padding-left', '10px');
});
```

So i tried to bind a event to overwrite the response ,but its throwing error 
**$.ui.autocomplete is undefined**

the application is loading

but i have the  reference in my xslt (everything is inside xslt and the jason string is received from handler for autocomplete).

Below code works fine ,except the text is not getting added

```
var options, a;
jQuery(function()
{
    a = $('#txtOccupation').autocomplete({
        serviceUrl: '/App_Handlers/GetAjaxSuggestions.ashx?datasets=occ',
        minChars: 1,
        delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/,
        deferRequestBy: 0, //miliseconds
        noCache: false,
        width: 420,
        onSelect: function(value, data) {
            alert('You selected: ' + value + ', ' + data);
        },
        response: function(e, ui) {
            ui.content.unshift({label: "OR select an occupation:", value: "OR select an occupation:"});//not working...
        }
    });
    browser = jQuery.browser;
    $('.autocomplete').css('padding-left', '10px');
});
```

JSON format

```
{
    "query": 're',
    "suggestions": ['Real Estate Brokers', 'Real Estate Sales Agents'],
    "data": ['41902100', '41902200']
}
```

Comment: the master page use jQuery UI 1.7.2 , but in the xslt i am loading   <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js">
  </script>

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t7heB/ working fine for me

Comment: @susheel It works, but when i add the handler input , its not populating the source. source: '/App_Handlers/GetAjaxSuggestions.ashx?datasets=occ', . The handler op will be in above format.

Comment: `{
    "query": 're',
    "suggestions": ['Real Estate Brokers', 'Real Estate Sales Agents'],
    "data": ['41902100', '41902200']
}`

this is what you are getting but autosuggestion is not populating ?

Comment: yes.. the code i posted above works fine. But when i try the way of coding in fiddle its not working.I tried even before.. Is there anything wrong in the way of accessing the string for this method..My above code uses jQuery UI 1.7.2

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

I don't see a serviceUrl in doc..is it dotnet specific jquery autocomplete ?

Comment: `/App_Handlers/GetAjaxSuggestions.ashx?datasets=occ` exactly

what does this url return ??? where are you getting the data from

Comment: This is the exact op from handler {
    "query": 're',
    "suggestions": ['Real Estate Brokers', 'Real Estate Sales Agents'],
    "data": ['41902100', '41902200']
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
jQuery(function() {
   $('#txtOccupation').autocomplete({
        serviceUrl: '/App_Handlers/GetAjaxSuggestions.ashx?datasets=occ',
        minChars: 1,
        delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/,
        deferRequestBy: 0, //miliseconds
        noCache: false,
        width: 420,
        onSelect: function(value, data) {
              alert('You selected: ' + value + ', ' + data);
        },beforeRender: function (container) {
              container.prepend("<div class='autocomplete-suggestion'>OR select an occupation:</div>");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: tried the above code ,request.query is undefined . so changed to request.term . But still no response.

Comment: No luck. i tried to debug ,the result varible is undefined. In above original post ,the code under "Below code works fine ,except the text is not getting added " . Is there any way to add the text OR select an occupation: when the dropdown opens..

Comment: while returning ,data has nothing ,other than searchterm=reg//inputtext

Comment: `beforeRender: function (container) {}` use this..there is nothing called repsonse with the jquery.autocomplete which you are using

Comment: @Vani you confused us with jqueryui autocomplete and jquery ajax autocomplete. both are completely different and u mixed both of them

Comment: yes you are right. I was going through the github just before seeing your comment. Thanks for pointing. i am trying to access the container .. will update u

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52542/discussion-between-vani-and-susheel)